# (Next 12.2) Chaining Middleware

Tags: next.js, middleware

I am looking to chain middleware in a nextJS project, on the latest NextJS version with the stable Middleware API. Here's an example snippet of my `middleware.ts` file.

Both of these will return a `NextResponse` object, how can I go about chaining them so the cookies are added first then passed along to find redirects?

I suppose I'll have to extend the API of the second middleware to take in the response and use it's contents or pass it along. Does anyone have a good example for how to go about this?

```
export const middleware = (req: NextRequest): NextResponse | undefined => {
  addCookieMiddleware(req);
  findRedirectsMiddleware(req);

// How to return a singular NextResponse object with the cookie attached and the correct URL to redirect?
}
```

Comment: nextjs uses express under the hood, this may help https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to chain as well.

The docs say you can chain https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server#static-methods

> next() - Returns a NextResponse that will continue the middleware chain

Here is the source code for v12.2.2 (current at the time of writing)
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/689626c6a4d509fe04aaf82c9971a5928669bcf4/packages/next/server/web/spec-extension/response.ts#L64

```js
static next(init?: ResponseInit) {
  const headers = new Headers(init?.headers)
  headers.set('x-middleware-next', '1')
  return new NextResponse(null, { ...init, headers })
}
```

If it does chain, I think it has to do something with the `x-middleware-next` header it is setting. I looked through the source code and I still could not determine how to chain.

The other interesting thing is `next()` returns a new `NextResponse` ,but, `next()` is a static method.

Since `next()` is static, you cannot call twice.

This does not work, `response` will be undefined.

```js
const response = NextResponse.next()
response.next({
  headers: {
    'a-test': Math.random().toString(),
  },
})
```

---

What I'm doing for now:

You set cookies by calling `next()` and using the public cookie property and use `Map` operations.

```js
const response = NextResponse.next()
response.cookies.set('a-test', Math.random().toString())
```

You set headers by calling `next()` and passing in an object with a `headers` object within.

```js
const response = NextResponse
response.next({
  headers: {
    'a-test': Math.random().toString(),
  },
})
```

I first thought was to use `const response = new NextResponse` but that did not work, `response` would always be undefined. You have to use `const response = NextResponse`

Since you can only call `next()` once, the best thing I could do was call the headers function first where calling `next()` is required, and then calling the function that sets the cookies.

```js
// middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

const setHeaders = (response) => {
  return response.next({
    headers: {
      'a-test': Math.random().toString(),
    },
  }
}

const setCookies = (response) => {
  response.cookies.set('a-test', Math.random().toString())
  return response
}

export async function middleware(request) {
  // Limitation in config matcher, requires me to exclude here
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next')) {
    return NextResponse.next()
  }

  let response = NextResponse
  response = setHeaders(response) 
  response = setCookies(response)
  return response
}
```

Hope this helps!